# Is it possible to combine HDR with MSAA in a DirectX 12 desktop application?

Tags: directx-12, hdr, msaa, direct3d12

Using the DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12, I'm able to successfully compile and run the individual MSAA and HDR tutorial samples.
When I combined the relevant code for the MSAA and HDR components together into a single **Game.cpp** file however, compilation fails with the debug layer message:

*D3D12 ERROR : ID3D12CommandList::ResolveSubresource : The specified format is not compatible with the source resource.Format : R10G10B10A2_UNORM, Source Resource Format : R16G16B16A16_FLOAT [RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #878: RESOLVESUBRESOURCE_INVALID_FORMAT]*

I am using the HDR sample code for an SDR display monitor, and therefore need to apply tone mapping. With respect to the order in which calls are made, I make a call to end the HDR scene before attempting to resolve the MSAA render target:

```
// 3d rendering completed
m_hdrScene->EndScene(commandList);

if (m_msaa)
{
    // Resolve the MSAA render target.
    //PIXBeginEvent(commandList, PIX_COLOR_DEFAULT, L"Resolve");

    auto backBuffer = m_deviceResources->GetRenderTarget();
    ...
```

Then following the MSAA resolve block, I place the tone mapping statement as follows:

```
// Unbind depth/stencil for sprites (UI)
auto rtvDescriptor = m_deviceResources->GetRenderTargetView();
commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtvDescriptor, FALSE, nullptr);

// set texture descriptor heap in prep for sprite drawing
commandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(static_cast<UINT>(std::size(heaps)), heaps);

// apply tonemapping to hdr scene
switch (m_deviceResources->GetColorSpace())
{
default:
    m_toneMap->Process(commandList);
    break;
...
```

I found that attempting to tone map *before* setting the descriptor heap for drawing 2D sprites (over the 3D scene) would result in the error:

*D3D12 ERROR: CGraphicsCommandList::SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable: The descriptor heap (0x0000025428203230:'DescriptorHeap') containing handle 0x80000253a82ff205 is different from currently set descriptor heap 0x0000025428203540:'EffectTextureFactory'. [ EXECUTION ERROR #708: SET_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE_INVALID]
D3D12: **BREAK** enabled for the previous message, which was: [ ERROR EXECUTION #708: SET_DESCRIPTOR_TABLE_INVALID ]*

I admit this was a rather naive first attempt to combine HDR and MSAA, but I'm concerned that these features could be incompatible and/or mutually exclusive in DirectX 12. I understand why a resource compatibility issue arises during MSAA resolve, as we need to use floating point render targets for HDR. I should note that my program will run and render correctly with HDR if I skip the MSAA code blocks by setting my **m_msaa** boolean to *false*.

Looking forward to any advice anyone may have. If sufficient code or other details about the program are required, I'll be happy to update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResolveSubresource` cannot do the conversion from 16fp to 10:10:10:2 HDR10.

Generally you need to:

1. Render to MSAA floating-point in High Dynamic Range (linear color space)
2. Resolve MSAA to single-sample floating-point. (Many games choose to use advanced software antialiasing techniques as part of this process such as FXAA, SMAA, etc.)
3. Perform the tone-map and Rec.2020 colorspace conversion from floating-point to 10:10:10:2
4. Display HDR10

> Rendering the UI sometimes happen before step 3, other times after. If done before, you typically have to 'scale up' the UI colors to make them stand out.

See the [SimpleMSAA DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/PCSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleMSAA_PC12) and [SimpleHDR DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/PCSamples/Graphics/SimpleHDR_PC12) samples for the technical details.

*DirectX Tool Kit* includes a `PostProcess` class which can perform the HDR10 tone-map. See [this tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Using-HDR-rendering).

Comment: Thank you @ChuckWalbourn, I followed your steps and can report success!

Comment: Key changes to the code include:
1. Setting up MSAA render targets with a 16fp texture format.
2. Managing resource barrier transitions during MSAA resolve for both the target HDR texture and the main backbuffer render target.
Am happy to post the solution in a separate post for anyone interested.
Just want to say my experience with the DirectXTK as a primary toolset for developing in DirectX 12 has been overwhelmingly positive.

Answer (score 1):

To successfully render a HDR scene with 4xMSAA, I made the following revisions:

1. In **CreateWindowSizeDependentResources()**, the MSAA render target (and view) are defined with the same format as the HDR render texture:

   ```
    // Create an MSAA render target.
    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC msaaRTDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Tex2D(
    //m_deviceResources->GetBackBufferFormat(),
    m_hdrScene->GetFormat(), // set matching format to HDR target (_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT)
    backBufferWidth,
    backBufferHeight,
    1, // This render target view has only one texture.
    1, // Use a single mipmap level
    4  // <--- Use 4x MSAA
    );
    ...
   ```
2. The next major change is in **Render()**, where the MSAA resolve to the HDR target occurs *after* ending the HDR scene render and *before* the tone mapping process:

   ```
    // Resolve the MSAA render target.
    auto backBuffer = m_deviceResources->GetRenderTarget();
    auto hdrBuffer = m_hdrScene->GetResource(); // HDR destination texture

    {
        D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER barriers[2] =
        {
            // transition msaa texture from target to resolve source
            CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(
                m_msaaRenderTarget.Get(),
                D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET,
                D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RESOLVE_SOURCE),
            // transition hdr texture from pixel shader resource to resolve destination
            CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(
                hdrBuffer,
                D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE,
                D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RESOLVE_DEST)
        };

        commandList->ResourceBarrier(2, barriers);
    }

    //commandList->ResolveSubresource(backBuffer, 0, m_msaaRenderTarget.Get(), 0,
    //    m_deviceResources->GetBackBufferFormat());

    // resolve MSAA to the single sample 16FP resource destination
    commandList->ResolveSubresource(hdrBuffer, 0, m_msaaRenderTarget.Get(), 0,
        m_hdrScene->GetFormat());

    // prepare backbuffer for 2D sprite drawing, typically rendered without MSAA
    {
        D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER barriers[2] =
        {
            // transition hdr texture from resolve destination back to p.s resource
            CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(
                hdrBuffer,
                D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RESOLVE_DEST,
                D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE),
            // transition backbuffer from Present to render target (for sprite drawing after the MSAA resolve)
            CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(
                backBuffer,
                D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT,
                D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET)
        };
        commandList->ResourceBarrier(2, barriers);
    }

    ... do tone mapping
    ... do 2D sprite drawing
   ```

Output was to a conventional 1080p display (no HDR10 or V-Sync). The LHS screen capture is a HDR scene without MSAA, whereas the RHS capture shows the smoothing effect of 4xMSAA on the 3D wireframe objects, kettle & earth models, and triangle billboard.
The cat and 'Hello World' text are 2D sprites drawn to the backbuffer after MSAA resolve and tone mapping.

Thanks again to @ChuckWalbourn for pointing me in the right direction, and I look forward to progressing my projects with the DirectX Tool Kit.

Comment: Please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/66OXS.png for images.